# Count no of rows where two column's value mismatch

Tags: php, sql, ajax, database, count

I would like to count the number of rows where my two columns does not have equal values. 
Two column Names are:

1) visitdate
  2) revisitdate

I have tried this query but no success.

```
$reSchedule_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM requests WHERE visitdate <=> revisitdate");
```

I want to echo the number of rows where visitdate is not equal to revisitdate.

Thank you

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it, I think it will work for you

```
$reSchedule_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE `visitdate` != `revisitdate`");
```

Comment: Sql count showing 1 when there is no such row. But it works when replace Count(*) with *. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE visitdate <> revisitdate
```

<> is the "not equal" operator
<=> is the "NULL-safe equal to" operator